# Deleting a common folder bash

Tags: command-line

All I want to do is to remove a common folder (the folder `MS_`) and **copy** all of the contents of a file up one level.

e.g.:

```
R:\ABCD\Restores\RT\101451\2012-DEC-05\10886\MS_\JOHN\
```

becomes

```
R:\ABCD\Restores\RT\101451\2012-DEC-05\10886\JOHN\
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cd R:\ABCD\Restores\RT\101451\2012-DEC-05\10886\MS_\
mv JOHN ..
cd ../
rmdir MS_
```